# Why can I not call my function with the calling line of

Tags: c#

Why can I not call my function like I have it now? The code for the printDictionary works perfectly if I have it in the main method. I want to move it to a function and then just use it that way with passing in my parameter but it give errors which are listed at the bottom.

**Question: What have I missed that would cause me the errors below when I simply just want to call a function to print?**

```
    printDictionary(d); <-- Error
```

Calling Code:

```
    printDictionary(d);
```

Function to Call:

```
    private void printDictionary(Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>
                                                            InputDictionaryParm1)
    {
        foreach (var a in InputDictionaryParm1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Key);
            foreach (var e in a.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Name);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

---

Error Table:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.printDictionary(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.Employee>>)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\itpr13266\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  52  13  ConsoleApplication1
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<ConsoleApplication1.Employee>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.Employee>>'   C:\Users\itpr13266\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  52  29  ConsoleApplication1
```

Comment: How is `d` defined in the calling method?

Comment: your parameter `d` is not proper to send it to function, show us calling function code where `d` is declared

Comment: `d` is not a `Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>`, which is what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 5):

From the looks of the error you are trying to pass a SortedDictionary into a method that accepts a Dictionary. These two types are not the same and can't be used interchangeably. They do both however implement IDictionary, so you could probably change the signature of the method to use the interface instead of a specific class.

You might consider changing the method signature to:

```
private void printDictionary(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Employee>>                                                             InputDictionaryParm1)
{
    foreach (var a in InputDictionaryParm1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Key);
        foreach (var e in a.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Name);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I made two changes: switching from Dictionary to IDictionary and from List to IEnumerable. It doesn't appear you are using anything specific in List, so IEnumerable is a better choice (if all you need to do is enumerate over the values).

Comment: Almost. But look at the type parameters in the error as well. The TValue parameter should be List<Employee> but he's passing in SortedSet<Employee>. I imagine if he changes his method signature to `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Employee>>` his code will work.

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you what's going on:

> cannot convert from `'SortedDictionary<string,SortedSet<Employee>>'` to `'Dictionary<string,List<Employee>>'`

In other words, you've declared `d` as a `SortedDictionary<string,SortedSet<Employee>>` but your method is expecting a `Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>`.

You'll have to change one of these types, as [*Dismissile's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201085/1715579) suggests, or convert between them. For example:

```
printDictionary(d.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.ToList()));
```